# validate file content with bash Regular Expressions + Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, regular-expressions

how to validate the following file content

that should be include single integer/float number 
by bash Regular Expression or any other idea with awk/sed

```
 cat  /var/VERSION/Version_F35_project_usa
 2.8
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your regexp is /\A\d+.?\d+\Z/g

Comment: You would need to give at least an example of how to use that regex.